# Инициализация переменных унаследованных от абстрактного класса

Tags: java, наследование, конструктор

Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
public abstract class Duck {
    FlyBehavior flyBehavior;
    QuackBehavior quackBehavior;
}
public class MallardDuck extends Duck {
    public MallardDuck(){
        quackBehavior = new Quack();
        flyBehavior = new FlyFithWings();
    }
}
```

Почему нельзя проинициализировать переменные в классе-наследнике не в конструкторе?

Ведь мы унаследовались от Duck.

Comment: почему вы решили что нельзя?

Comment: А чем плоха инициализация полей суперкласса в конструкторе? Копилятор то всё равно запихнёт это в конструктор.

Comment: начал читать книгу Head First паттерны и там есть такой пример, начал его вводить и как-то машинально хотел проинициализировать переменные, идея начала ругаться, поэтому и решил что нельзя. В данном конкретном примере идея не дает скомпилировать класс MallardDuck если пытаешься инициализировать переменные(которые как мне до этого казалось должны быть унаследованы от класса Duck). Так я понял, что что-то упустил разбираясь с абстрактными классами(собственно разбираться я только начал, поэтому строго не судите)

Comment: Также можно сделать инициализацию полей суперкласса вызывая конструктор класса Duck из MallardDuck. В шарпе это делается через ключевое слово base, ну а в джаве, наверное, через super

Comment: я просто разобраться хочу, мы ведь унаследовали эти поля от Duck т.е.насколько я это представил в нашем коде как-бы есть уже эти поля. Раз так, то почему я не могу присвоить им значение в классе MallardDuck не в конструкторе? класс Duck абстрактный

Comment: ...не в конструкторе - а где вы пытаетесь это сделать? Вы, например можете их инициализировать в блоке инициализации.

Comment: а почему нельзя просто в теле класса-наследника?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Почему нельзя проинициализировать переменные просто в теле класса-наследника?

Так решили создатели языка Java.

Согласно спецификации ([§8.1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6)) тело класса состоит из:

- объявлений членов класса: методов, полей, вложенных классов и интерфейсов;
- инициализаторов экземпляра класса;
- статических инициализаторов;
- объявлений конструкторов класса.

Как видите присвоения значений полям класса в списке нет. Впрочем, это можно сделать с помощью инициализатора экземпляра, который оформляется отдельным блоком внутри класса:

```
public class MallardDuck extends Duck {
    { 
        quackBehavior = new Quack();
        flyBehavior = new FlyFithWings();
    }
}
```

Но мне легче читать код в котором логика заключена в конструкторы: так сразу видно что происходит при создании класса. Блоки инициализации легче пропустить при чтении, легче забыть про них. Такие блоки могут привести к путанице, особенно если использовать их вперемешку с методами/конструкторами.

Как правило люди рекомендуют использовать инициализаторы только если без них сложно/невозможно обойтись. Такие ситуации встречаются достаточно редко (см. [Should I use initializer blocks in Java?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238820/should-i-use-initializer-blocks-in-java)).

Могли ли разработчики спецификации языка разрешить то же самое только без блока инициализации? Наверное, да, ведь это не что иное как менее удобочитаемый вариант инициализатора. По-видимому, такая возможность не показалась им полезной и/или удобной.

Comment: спасибо большое, всё ясно и предельно понятно. Самообразование оно такое, вроде и понимаешь, но не до конца, иногда необходимы такие вот конкретные подсказки

Comment: @ConstantinPlahetka Пожалуйста! Добро пожаловать на сайт.